# News Feed Which Updates With New Content On A Timer

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, express, timer

I have a news feed and want to refresh it's content with 15 new posts every 5 minutes. On my html page, I have a paragraph tag which acts as the countdown timer. When the timer reaches 0, I want to update the feed.

I know I could use 'setInterval(300000)' on the client side to request new posts every 5 minutes. However, I need the timer to exist independent of the client so that the feed is populated with new data at the same time for each user.

Would I be right to wrap a database request in a 'setInterval(300000)' function on the server-side, and somehow have it push the returned data to the client for processing? If so, what would be the best approach to sending that data to the client?

Continuing with this, how might I sync the timer in my html with the current countdown time on the server? Would it make sense to somehow use socket.io to keep a connection open and send the current time over from the server to the client? If so, what might that connection look like?

I am using 'Backbone.js' as my front-end framework, and 'node.js' with 'express', and 'socket.io' on the back-end.

I am familiar with synchronizing the views with the models on the front end. My question is more about how to populate the models with the necessary data to complete my task.

Any help, or direction to where I might find some help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way to send data from server to clients if clients don't make a request.

You need to find the way to let clients make request same time you want (every 5 minutes server time).

1. In server code, define time you want to send request(every 5 min like 10h15, 10h20,...)
2. In client, when user login or online, send next time to make request to client.
   Just use setTimeout with this time client take from server, you can get new post from server very easy.